# How to format a lookup relationship apex:inputField box look okay in bootstrap

Tags: visualforce, bootstrap

I tried to use bootstrap with apex:inputField. Usually it works fine. But when it comes to lookup relationship, the field looks like this:

[image]

Is there any quick fix to make it looking okay? By applying some typeahead library we can probably fix this but this will be a lot of javascript code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a bit of CSS to fix this .Here is a [handy blog](https://www.codescience.com/blog/2015/bootstrap-your-salesforce-lookups) that shows how to do it .

[image]

```
<apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!contact.reportsToId}" />
```

The CSS would like below

[image]

```
/* lookup field override */
.lookupInput a {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
.lookupInput img {
    float: right;
}
span.lookupInput {
    position: relative;
    display: inherit;
}
.lookupInput a, .lookupInput a {
    border: none !important;
    background: none !important;
}
/* end lookup field override */
```

Comment: That's pretty sweet, but couldn't you provide a copy-paste (text) version of the code?

Comment: Really lazy to copt things from the blogpost !!!!!!

Comment: lol !! Was about to  put the code now !!! Saw the edit from you .Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. I type like 100 wpm anyways, so it wasn't a big deal.

Comment: @sfdcfox there is no doubt about your wpm speed :) lol